# CSV encoding type with Flatworm

Tags: java, xml, excel, csv, encoding

I have an application, which reads a table from a database, by using the Flatworm Framework. It generates a .csv file, which can be downloaded.

In the .XML Mapping File from Flatworm I have to set: `<file-format encoding="WINDOWS-1252">`

The table contains among others following letters: `ö,ä,é,à,ß,ü,ç,ã`

But when I open the .csv, the letters are not encoded correctly.

I used `UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, WINDOWS-1252, ISO-8859-1`

Can somebody help?

Comment: The right encoding should be `Cp1252`. But the difference to `ISO-8859-1` is minimal. Please show the code where you read the file. Maybe there is a bug in it.

Comment: You should also verify the CSV file*s  actual encoding. Is it really Windows-ANSI? Some editors like Notepad++ or PsPad are able to determine the encoding of a file.